# Validate html form with javascript after html automatic validation

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make a little form with some fields like name, age or email. For example:

```
<input id="name" type="text" required/>
```

I have a problem with the validation because i want to use the automatic validation of html to check that all fields with the required tag aren't empty and, after that, validate some fields (like the email) with javascript. I have a submit input element like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="form.validate()" />
```

The problem is that the onclick method (validate()) is always called before the auto validation, and what i want to do is call that method afther the auto validation ends (and it's everything right). The javascript i'm using to test looks like this:

```
"use strict";
class Form {
    constructor(){}
    validate(){
        alert("validate");
    }
}
var form = new Form();
```

The alert is always shown, but the auto validation it's not. If i don't put the onclick tag with its method on the submit button, the auto validation works. Any idea about my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the directive `ng-submit` in your form:

```
<form ng-submit="form.validate()" ng-controller="YourController">    
   <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action

Keep Rocking!

Comment: Now it makes the auto validation first, but the alert from the javascript is not shown

Comment: The alert would be fire when all the inputs are correctly completed.

Comment: I complete all the fields of the form properly, the auto validation checks everything is right and submits the form, but the javascript code seems to be not executing, because the alert is still not shown.

Comment: @novayhulk14 This uses angularjs, which I am a huge fan of, but it is not using vanilla js, and if you aren't including angular in to your project, ng-submit will never run your function.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses jQuery. First you need to prevent the default action on form submit, then you can do your validation, then finally submit the form. Example below.

Your form:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Javascript(with jQuery):

```
$('#form').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
    /* Validations go here */
    form.validate();
    alert('here');
    this.submit(); // If all the validations succeeded
});
```

JavaScript(vanilla):

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
    /* Validations go here */
    alert('here');
    this.submit(); // If all the validations succeeded
});
```